# using schema files with decimals for datastage file sequence import

Tags: database, etl, datastage

I have a series of CSV's I import into a database via Datastage.  I am attempting to do this using RCP and schema files.

I generate the schema files from the CSVs using an accompanied master table list that comes with the CSVs.

I am down to one problem.  When I find that a numeral is the last column in a particular table, it is the last entry in a schema file.  My problem is null handling.  The CSV is comma-delimited, double quoted for strings, and no data for null.

The master list identifies some of these number columns as number(), which is indicative of an oracle description of the output.  To that end, I am trying this:

:nullable decimal[38,9] { default=0, text };
in this example, the scale and precision are defaulted, to 38,9....unless specified elsewhere, such as decimal[10,2].

A null entry results in this error: 
When validating import/export function: APT_GFIX_Decimal::validateParameters: the decimal "text" format is variable length, and no external length is specified;
you should possibly specify an appropriate "width" property; external format: {text, padchar=32, nofix_zero, precision=38, scale=9, round=trunc_zero, ascii}. [decimal/impexp.C:939]

so I tried:
:nullable decimal[38,9] { default=0, text, width=47 };
in this example, the scale and precision are defaulted, to 38,9.  The width is the sum of the two values (38 + 9 = 47...unless specified elsewhere, such as decimal[10,2].

and I got:
ODBC_Connector_3,0: Input buffer overrun at field "", at offset: ### [impexp/group_comp.C:6006]

Lastly, I tried exactly what it said, and did this:
:nullable decimal[38,9] { default=0, text, padchar=32, nofix_zero, precision=, scale=, round=trunc_zero, ascii, width=47 };
in this example, the scale and precision are defaulted, to 38,9.  The width is the sum of the two values (38 + 9 = 47...unless specified elsewhere, such as decimal[10,2].

For this third time, I received this error:  Input buffer overrun at field "", at offset: ### [impexp/group_comp.C:6006]

Has anyone ran into this?  this only happens if decimal is the last column in the table.

my record settings are: {intact, final_delim=none, record_delim='\n', charset='UTF8', delim=','}

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you need to set the default value for the field when it is null to the maximum length of the field. For example, in char(x) fields nullable, I am used to set a default value like '   ' [ space character pad x times ] in order to handle all null values or potential errors of buffer overrun. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried to put the solutions mentioned in the above answer as well as question. It didnt work. Turned out, my target column had - decimal(14,10), i.e. 4 digits before decimal point and 10 digits after decimal point. I was getting null values in the target even though i had actual data at the source. But the issue was source had more than 4 digits before the decimal. I modified target and source column to decimal(16.10). On top of this, like mentioned in the question, we shouldn’t put decimal columns in the end when we are using schema files. I put a string column in the end at source, Combined both of these and viola! I could see my data properly loaded in the target.